# Meaning of error in Codeigniter : "Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class My_connection model"

Tags: php, codeigniter

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class My_connection in C:\wamp\www\mvc\smsc\application\models\my_connection.php on line 38

I created a model My_connection. I am calling this method into  the constructor of my controller. 
Every error has meaning. What is the reason behind that error. 
Please, tell the meaning of error. What can be cause. I have read out the many question relating to this. All questions and their answer somewhat different. They try to correct the code. I want to know the reason. 
Please, help relative to question.

```
<?php
class My_connection extends CI_Model{
public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
}

public function is_connected(){
    $session_id=$this->session->userdata('session_id');
    $session_username=$this->session->userdata('username');
    $session_password=$this->session->userdata('password');
    $this->db->select('session_id');
    $this->db->from('ci_sessions');
    $this->db->where('session_id',$session_id);
    $ses_query=$this->db->get();
    if($ses_query->num_rows>0){
    foreach($ses_query->rows as $row){
    $session_db_id=$ses_query->row();   
    }
    }
    $this->db->select('username','password');
    $this->db->from('users');
    $this->db->where('username',$session_username);
    $user_query=$this->db->get();
    if($user_query->num_rows()>0){
    foreach($user_query->result() as $row){
    $password=$row->password;
    $username=$row->username;   
    }
    }

    if( md5($password)==$session_password AND $username==$session_username AND  $session_db_id==$session_id){
        return TRUE;
    }
    else {
        return FALSE;
    }`enter code here`
}
}
/**
* End of file my_connection.php
* Location: application/models/my_connection.php
*/`
```

Last line is 38. According to error. I have no understanding to solve it.

Comment: You can also use a `Namespace` if you really want to keep the name the same...but changing the name is easiest!

Comment: `class My_connection`--declared more than once.

Comment: Problem is solved. Actually, I name the controller and model with same name. I saw this convention in many tutorial and in the documents of CodeIgniter. I name the class and used the prefix My_ for both controller and model with same name. To solve the problem and being familiar with controller and model class. I used this convention Myc_ for controller. Mym_ for model. after that problem is solved. I think, it is stupid solution. But, it work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message is clear: you can't to declare a new class with a name already used in your app.

I used to put a prefix to my models (eg: `My_connection_model`) to avoid these errors.

Comment: I used prefix Mym_ for model and Myc_ for controller. It help me to differentiate between controller and model class.

Answer (score 0):

I had the above problem. Now, I have solved it. The solution is stupid. But, it work. Actually, the reason to create to such error:

- when It  conflict with its own core classes
- When, your controller class and model class has same name. While, this is not absolute reason. Because, I run many programs like that. At that time, It show no error. with changing of some configuration, when you try to load. It give error. I solved my error by assigning different names to controller class and model class.

To avoid the problem.

- use different prefix for controller and model class.Like Myc_ for controller or Mym_ for model.

> Note: This is not complete answer. I think, this explanation is not enough to clear the meaning of error. If someone has different solution or meaning to this error. Please, share your solution.